# SATA Caddy For HP G60-230US Laptop CD/DVD Drive

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I just installed a SSD in my HP G60-230US laptop and would like to use the HDD as a second drive in the CD/DVD bay.

Does anyone know who sell a SATA caddy that would work for my laptop?  I emailed caddy vendors on Amazon market place and ebay but they cannot tell me that their products would work in my HP laptop model.

Answer (score 1):

The beauty of laptop optical drives, is that aside from the tray panel and how it attaches to the tray, the rest of the drive is universal.  Your laptop uses a standard optical drive, and it could make use of a true universal replacement slim drive (the kind where the drive "door" is no wider/taller than the dimensions of the drive).  So, yes... any number of the ones I found on Amazon will work in your laptop.  [Several at Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=laptop%20optical%20drive%20bay%20caddy).  Note, I'm not talking about a 9.5mm Ultra slim drive... I'm talking about a standard 12.7mm slim drive.  Your laptop doesn't use an Ultra Slim drive.